# Twitter WordCloud Using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, twitter, word-cloud

I want to create a word cloud in nodejs. The user can search for tweet and based on the user input, a word cloud for that tweet will be displayed. I could see so many examples in R and few in nodejs. But nothing explained on how to search twitter and display a word cloud based on the search results. Any advice?

Comment: This is too broad, try asking a more specific question. Use [Twitter Api](https://dev.twitter.com/) for searching twitter. The tag cloud will be based on analyzing frequencies and there are many ways to do that e.g. using d3.js

Answer (score 0):

To search twitter use the [Twitter REST api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search). Use the returned values for your word cloud ! To build a word cloud use a library like d3.js or [tag cloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tag-cloud) !

Hope I got your question right !

Answer (score 0):

Start by searching for a Twitter package for node. I use Twit, but there are others you will find by searching at npmjs.com. For display, I use d3.js. But again, you have many other options depending on whether you want to put your cloud in a browser or in a stand-alone program. It looks like you are just starting out with this project, so begin with Twitter.

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thanks for your reply. I tried using twit and am able to see some feeds with the T.get('search/tweets'..... ). But then how do I pass those data to D3JS? I would have to split sentences into words and remove all spaces, punctuations etc, also look for the most frequently occurring words. Any idea how I can achieve all these using D3?

Comment: @Katie You could use the socket.io package for node.